# Redshift VACUUM cannot run inside a transaction block on SQLWorkbenchJ

Tags: vacuum, sql-workbench-j

I have got a:

> VACUUM cannot run inside a transaction block

error on SQLWorkbenchJ in Redshift, but I already commit all transactions before this.

Comment: After turn on 'Autocommit' at connection window,  'vacuum' can running normally.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You don't need to change the connection profile, you can change the autocommit property inside your SQL script "on-the-fly" with [set autocommit](http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/wb-commands.html#command-set-autocommit)

```
set autocommit on;
vacuum;
set autocommit off;
```

You can also toggle the current autocommit state through the menu "SQL -> Autocommit"

Comment: Hi , I got a error message when I run these 3 sql commands in SQLWorkBenchJ :   ERROR: syntax error at or near "on"
  Position: 17

Comment: @TingJia: works for me. Maybe you are using an old version of SQL Workbench.

Comment: Supposedly I am not doing any kind of transaction & I want to execute only VACCUM & ANALYZE through Redshift JDBC, is it possible??

Comment: @Akki: As I said: turn on autocommit

Comment: 'set autocommit on;' is invalid syntax, at least on redshift. instead use:  
    " commit; vacuum; commit;  "
in one line

Comment: @Chris.Caldwell: but SQL Workbench supports that (see the link in my answer)

Comment: I got the "
ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) syntax error at or near "on" " error.

Answer (score 13):

For me this worked.

```
END TRANSACTION;
VACCUM <TABLENAME>;
```

Answer (score 10):

turning autocommit on and off seems like a hacky solution particularly if you have a long script punctuated with commits and vacuums (ie lots of very large temp tables). Instead, try (in one line). Also, many are reporting redshift does not like the syntax. Instead,

```
COMMIT;VACUUM;COMMIT;
```

The problem is that vacuum not only wants to be the first command in a transaction block, it wants the block to be explicitly committed after.